# Changing the bitmap shown in a PictureBox for different TrackBar values

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I'm trying to use a TrackBar to control the image that is show in a PictureBox. There are 4 values for the TrackBar (0-4) and four images. The TrackBar's default value is 0 and currently I have set the Background image property to the image I would like to represent the 0 value (not sure if this is even the correct way to start).

so far i'v tried:

```
    private void TrackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TrackBar1.Value == 1)
        {
            PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Image2))
        }
    }
```

but this hasn't worked. I've got all the relevant images in the resources file all saved as bitmaps...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, still learning the ropes

Thanks

Harry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not to worry I solved it myself, the code I had used worked, I'd just forgotten to update the scroll event property to the TrackBar1_Scroll Event